# How to get current location using react-native-maps

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

Im trying to render a map at the current user geolocation on android device, using react-native maps.

Here is what i've got so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

class MapComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0,
      },
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

      var initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }

      this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
    },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000});
  }


  renderScreen = () => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}/>
        </View>
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.renderScreen()
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

export default MapComponent;
```

The map renders, but not in current device geolocation, as expected. (it renders in the middle of the ocean)

The permissions are already set at AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

After 20 seconds, i get an alert saying, "Location request timed out" "code 3"

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((info) => {
      let lat = info.coords.latitude;
      let long = info.coords.longitude;

      console.log(lat);
      console.log(long);
      var initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      };
      this.setState({ initialPosition: initialRegion });
    });

Comment: Use this function it will solve your problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure but there is an [issue ("Geolocation timed out, code 3")](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12996#issuecomment-324238609) which looks related

> For anyone else struggling with this issue on android, try removing
>   the maximumAge: 2000 option parameter. This option was causing
>   geolocation to either timeout or crash the app.

Answer (score 7):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

const App = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    latitude: 10,
    longitude: 10,
    latitudeDelta: 0.001,
    longitudeDelta: 0.001,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      const crd = pos.coords;
      setPosition({
        latitude: crd.latitude,
        longitude: crd.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={position}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      showsMyLocationButton={true}
      followsUserLocation={true}
      showsCompass={true}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      zoomEnabled={true}
      pitchEnabled={true}
      rotateEnabled={true}>
       <Marker
       title='Yor are here'
       description='This is a description'
       coordinate={position}/>
       </MapView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});


export default App;
```

Comment: this is working. also add permissions
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Answer (score 1):

It's working perfectly in mine. Only change I made was in `StyleSheet`.

```
container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height : SCREEN_HEIGHT,
    width : SCREEN_WIDTH,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
}
```

Thereafter, it renders my location. You can add marker after that to show your location.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. the third option is what was creating the prob.

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() =>{

},
 err => {

},
{ enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000}, //this worked for me
```

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is deprecated.
Use `@react-native-community/geolocation` instead.

```
npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save
```

Comment: [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) is much better

Comment: `@react-native-community/geolocation` seems to be deprecated, upvote for @ggDeGreat.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// global.currentScreenIndex = 'Dashboard';
//Import all required component
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StatusBar,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Button,
  NetInfo,
} from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";

const MyStatusBar = ({ backgroundColor, ...props }) => (
  <View style={[styles.statusBar, { backgroundColor }]}>
    <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor={backgroundColor} {...props} />
  </View>
);
   

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0,
      },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((info) => {
      let lat = info.coords.latitude;
      let long = info.coords.longitude;

      console.log(lat);
      console.log(long);
      var initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      };
      this.setState({ initialPosition: initialRegion });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { modalVisible } = this.state;
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    // const token_data = token_value();
    // console.log("token_homes_2st"+token_data);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}
          showsUserLocation={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    fontWeight: "400",
    color: "#000",
    fontFamily:
      "Inter UI,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif",
  },

  map: {
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -2):

1.npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save 
2.import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation'; 
3.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition => Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain in a little more detail how your described step help answering the question.